# While loop increments in c

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, increment, nested-loops

I am trying to make my "Steps" or increments in a while loop such that my values of are like N=2, 4, 8, 16... basically powers of 2 till 2^20. I have tried to do

```
for(j=1;j<=20;j++){
    m=pow(2,2*i); 
    MAX=pow(2,20); 
    INC=pow(2,i);
while(m<=MAX){
```

then have my code running inside this. But in the output it gives me 2,4,6,8,10,12.. does anyone know what the right way is to do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide proper code, please? This snippet hardly makes sense

Comment: you could just use `m=1<<j;` instead of the `pow` function.  And setting `MAX=1<<20;` _before_ your `for` loop would be good, too.

Comment: Your loop is incrementing j, yet you're multiplying by i.  You do the exact same thing 20 times.

Comment: Do expect this to be some kind of novel `for ... while` construct? That doesn't exist, C has `for {}`, `while {}` and `do {} while` loops only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with a value of 2 for `m` and multiply `m` by two every iteration. As an optimization you can replace the multiplication by two with an left shift:

```
int MAX = pow(2, 20); 
int m = 2;
while(m <= MAX) {
    //do your work
    m <<= 1;
}
```

Comment: or even better shift left: m <<= 2

Comment: @Mellowcandle Shouldn't it be `m<<=1` :)

Comment: yes....hahaha, I was confused

Comment: Ohhhh I totally forgot about that and had made the last line of my while loop m=m+step, the m=m*2 works, thank you very much!

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui You are welcome my friend :)

Answer (score 2):

In each iteration of the while loop; multiply your variable by two.

```
int m = 2;
while(m < maxpow)
{
  m = m * 2;
  printf("%d\n", m);
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh I totally forgot about that and had made the last line of my while loop m=m+step, the m=m*2 works, thank you very much!

Comment: The idiomatic C way is `for(m = 2; m < maxpow; m *= 2) { .... }`. Nobody forces the reinit to be a simple `i++`. So you can step along a list by `for( p = head; p; p = p->next) { .... }`